# App Engine Custom Domain Routing (With Python/Flask)

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I'm trying to map my App Engine app services to url paths as defined by my dispatch.yaml file. Here's basically what my dispatch.yaml file looks like (file is sitting in the default service root directory):

```
dispatch:
  # Service 1
- url: "*/service-1/*"
  service: service1

  # Service 2
- url: "*/service-2/*"
  service: service2

  # Default service 
- url: "*/.*"
  service: default
```

It's my understanding that, with these dispatch configs, any requests coming into https://example.com will go to the default service,  requests coming to https://example.com/service-1 will route to service1, https://example.com/service-2 will route to service2, and so on.

When I go to https://example.com, I am brought to my default service, as expected. However, when I navigate to https://example.com/service-1, I get a "404 Not Found" error. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I've already set up my custom domain according to the instructions listed here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains

I should also mention that I have built my apps using a combination of flask + python. Here's the app.yaml file for service1 (basically the same for default, with service: default instead):

```
runtime: python39
service: service1
handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

I've tried multiple configurations of the dispatch.yaml file, in addition to playing around with the app.yaml file configs for the individual services. The configs listed above are my most recent attempt

Comment: Does the flask app in service1 have a URL handler for `/service-1/` ? I assume the GCP load balancer is working correctly, and that the 404 error is coming from your app (confirm this!).

Comment: Ah - looks like that 404 error is indeed coming from my app (confirmed by going to the default GCP service url and putting in nonsense after the "/", i.e. https://SERVICENAME-dot-PROJECTNAME.uc.r.appspot.com/nonsensehere). How would I configure a handler to handle that in my main.py? Would it be another @app.route('/service-1/')?

Comment: I can further confirm (after tweaking the default 400 error page for the default service) that going to SERVICENAME-dot-PROJECTNAME.uc.r.appspot.com/service-1 does not route to service-1; it goes to the 400 error page for the default service.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current values of your `dispatch.yaml`, your stuff should work if you go to `https://example.com/service-1/` (notice the extra forward slash).

If you want to use your current value i.e. `https://example.com/service-1`, then you should change your `dispatch.yaml` to read

```
- url: "*/service-1*"
  service: service1
```

The downside is that it will match other stuff like `https://example.com/service-12`

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out per the feedback above (Thank you Danielle and NoCommandLine). I had to change the following in my main.py:

```
@app.route('/')
def root(): 
     return render_template("index.html")
```

To

```
@app.route('/service-1')
def root(): 
     return render_template("index.html")
```

Deployed this to my App Engine project and the routing is working as expected

Comment: I'll advise you add a trailing slash i.e. use ```(@app.route('/service-1/')``` . Read this [documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/quickstart/quickstart4.html) (look for the section - Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior) to understand why