# Configuring GCP App Engine with Flask App and Custom Domain

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I asked a question previously around getting my flask + GAE app engine app configured with a custom domain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77019141/app-engine-custom-domain-routing-with-python-flask/77024121#77024121).

I'm running into another issue. I am able to get to my service-1 app with my current dispatch.yaml config and via modifying the root() function in my main.py:

dispatch.yaml:

```
  # Service 1
- url: "*/service-1"
  service: service-1

  # Service 2
- url: "*/service-2"
  service: service-2
  
  # Default service 
- url: "*/.*"
  service: default
```

Here's the root() fuction in my app's main.py (service-1):

```
@app.route('/service-1')
def root(): 
     return render_template("index.html")
```

With the above configs, the application then successfully routes to index.html by going here: example.com/service-1

However, when I configure the app like this, it doesn't serve up any of the files in the static directory (custom css, js, etc.). I don't think I'm doing this correctly? Is there a standard way of configuring a flask app on GAE to serve up the custom domain's configured path (per dispatch.yaml) as "root" in the service-1 flask app?

I tried a few different configurations for the app.route and dispatch.yaml, and I also tried changing the default root path in main.py for service-1 here:

```
app = Flask(__name__, root_path='/service-1')
```

Comment: You need to configure the static file/dir handler in ```app.yaml```. See [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=python#configuring_your_static_file_handlers)

Comment: Coming back to this, the issue seems to only be impacting the "custom domain" version of the app (https://example.com/service-1). The direct link to the service has no issue getting the static files served properly (i.e. service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com).  In addition, when checking the contents of the style.css in example.com/service-1, I get "The requested URL /static/style.css was not found on this server."

Comment: The static file/dir handler is configured according to the documentation as well: - url: /static
  static_dir: static

Comment: Open your page in a browser, click to 'view page source', then look at the url of a static file. If what you have is a relative url (```/static/.....```), that could be the issue. Mouse over one of the urls and look at what appears at the bottom of your screen i.e. see if it gives you ```example.com/service-1/static/...``` or whether it gives ```example.com/static/....```

Comment: Ah - it looks like it's example.com/static/style.css, so this is likely the issue.  What would the handlers look like to properly route this? I've tried a few different configs but they don't seem to be sticking (i.e. changing `static_dir` to `example.com/service-1/static` seems to be ignored by the app, and it shows up as `example.com/static/style.css` again)

Comment: If you say you see ```example.com/static/style.css```, what do you see when you use GAE's direct url i.e. ```service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com```?

Comment: I see `https://service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com/static/style.css` when going to the project's GAE direct url. The header element itself is `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">`

Comment: FWIW, the static files are serving at the direct url correctly when I have the handlers set to `- url: /static static_dir: static`

Comment: If you see ```https://service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com/static/style.css``` and also ```https://example.com/static/style.css```, then both seem correct to me. It means your static files are relative to the root. I thought you were going to see ```https://example.com/service-1/static/style.css``` which is what I would think was incorrect (unless you're saying your static files are relative to a specific path i.e. ```/service-1``` and in that case I'd wonder how come the GAE direct url works). Will need to think about this a bit more

Comment: Yeah - I did try setting the static dir to the specific path you alluded to above during my attempts to troubleshoot this (`https://example.com/service-1/static`), and it did indeed break the gae direct service url css paths `https://service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com/static/style.css`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to leave an answer here for a workaround. Since the `https://service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com/static/style.css` was working, I included another `link` element underneath the regular `link` element in my `base.hmtl` header:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">`
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://service-1-dot-exampleproject.uc.r.appspot.com/static/style.css">
```

I would love to get this working the proper way, however.